# Restaurar .bak de más de 10GB

Tags: sql

Tengo que resturar un backup de una base de datos.

Estoy intentando restaurarlo pero no me carga la base de datos.
El .bak pesa 11GB

Probe a hacer una nueva base de datos y hacer una tabla y hacer una copia y si que me restaura bien.

¿Por qué puede ser?

Estoy usando SQL Server 2008 y 2014.

En 2014 no muestra nada, simplemente no me sale nada a restaurar

En 2008 me muestra un error, que es este:

```
Excepción al ejecutar una instrucción o un proceso por lotes Transact-SQL. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

La familia de medios del dispositivo 'C:\Temporal\backup_2018_10_23_210002_3944748.bak' no está formada correctamente. SQL Server no puede procesarla.
Fin anómalo de RESTORE HEADERONLY. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3241)

Para obtener ayuda, haga clic en: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4042&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3241&LinkId=20476

==================================

Excepción al ejecutar una instrucción o un proceso por lotes Transact-SQL. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
Ubicación del programa:

   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteWithResults(String sqlCommand)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteWithResults(String query)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupRestoreBase.ExecuteSqlWithResults(Server server, String cmd)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.ReadBackupHeader(Server srv)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.buttonSelectDevice_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

===================================

La familia de medios del dispositivo 'C:\Temporal\backup_2018_10_23_210002_3944748.bak' no está formada correctamente. SQL Server no puede procesarla.
Fin anómalo de RESTORE HEADERONLY. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
Para obtener ayuda, haga clic en: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4042&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3241&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Nombre del servidor: MI-PC\SQLEXPRESS
Número de error: 3241
Gravedad: 16
Estado: 0
Número de línea: 1


------------------------------
Ubicación del programa:

   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteWithResults(String sqlCommand)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas tratando de restaurar un Backup de la versión 2014 a la 2008 no vas a poder por tema de incompatibilidad, lo que te recomiendo es ir a SSMS hacer click derecho sobre la DB que deseas migrar, ir a Tasks -> Generate Scripts...  ,  ahí dejas el primer check marcado que dice que seleccionas todas las tablas y procedimientos, luego le das a "Siguiente", ahí en el botón "Avanzado" vas a la ultima opción del bloque de "General" y donde dice "Types of data to script" Selecciona la opción de "Data y Esquema". Luego el script que te genera lo ejecutas en la nueva base de datos y ya la tendrás sin problema de versiones   :)

Comment: no puedo volver a hacer otro backup...

Comment: Prueba descargar el SSMS de la versión de la Base de datos por ejemplo 2014 y restaurala ahí, una vez la tengas restaurada en la misma versión del SQL haces los pasos para exportarla vía scripts